# The Two Roads Problem: How many cars take Roads 1 and 2?

Tags: recreational-mathematics, problem-solving

Suppose the points A and B are connected by two roads of the length $S_1$ and $S_2$. Cars can drive from A to B on either of the two roads. They start at point A and must decide, **one after the other** which road to take. They know how many cars already chose to drive on each road.

The speed of all cars on a road is equal to $\frac{1}{\sqrt{(N)}}$, where $N$ is the number of cars driving on that road at any time.

What is the limit of the ratios of cars on road $1$ to road $2$ as the number of cars that arrive per unit of time tends to infinity?

EDIT: The drivers can make decisions instantly and are $100\%$ logical.

Comment: The economic answer (before your EDIT) is that you can take either road, since the other drivers (especially those after you) will make choices which will make the two times almost equal, with a difference smaller than the time you will need to calculate the answer

Comment: I understand what you mean and have added an EDIT to the question.

Comment: As the number of cars tends to infinity, the speed of cars on the roads will tend to zero, so it will be a logjam.

Comment: Here's a great place to start: http://web.mat.bham.ac.uk/R.W.Kaye/latex/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're better off looking for the long-run equilibrium result in the limit as time goes to infinity (assuming that interarrival times are small compared to the travel time), rather than as the arrival rate goes to infinity.

With that interpretation, at equilibrium, the travel times on the two roads are equal.  That is, the speeds on the two roads are proportional to their lengths.  Symbolically,

$$
\frac{S_2}{S_1} = \frac{1/\sqrt{N_2}}{1/\sqrt{N_1}} = \sqrt\frac{N_1}{N_2}
$$

This can be simplified to obtain

$$
\frac{N_2}{N_1} = \left(\frac{S_1}{S_2}\right)^2
$$

Comment: I think you have the right answer. Your definition of "the limit as time goes to infinity (assuming that interarrival times are small compared to the travel time)" is conceptually the same as what I was aiming for.

Comment: @DayVid: If so, I'm assuming you have insufficient reputation to upvote, so that leaves acceptance (or not).

Answer (score 0):

$$\lim_{N\to\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{N}}=0$$

Therefore the cars are stationary

But they are arriving infinitely many per second, so there is a pile up of infinitely many cars every instant.

100% logical drivers cannot make an instant decision in the face of an illogical universe containing an infinite pile-up of stationary vehicles. A contradiction.

Comment: Robert, think about it this way. If road 1 is shorter, cars will take road 1 until the square root of cars times the length of road 1 is longer than road 2. At that point, a car will take road 2. Then cars will go through road 1 again, until the square root of cars on road 1 times the length of road 1 is bigger than the square root of cars on road 2 times the length of road two. It does not matter if they are stationary. There is a limit to the ratio of cars that choose each road.